# flash release mouse capture on mouse out

Tags: flash, mouseevent, mousecapture

I have a flash app loaded in an iframe. User mouses down in flash and goes outside of stage. When user goes outside of stage, is there a way to release the mouse capture from flash so that parent receives further mouse events and not the flash app?

In Firefox and Chrome, parent doesn't receive events until the user mouses up
In IE, parent receives event when the user goes outside of stage.

Comment: Firefox and other have that behavior, IE has the opposite i think... watch what you wish for :) it will be a pain to replicate that across browsers...

Comment: but it should be possible through javascript and flash ExternalInterface

Comment: @Neoraptor: its actually opposite, IE has that behavior.

Comment: Thank you for noticing that :)

Comment: Err, you are doing it from an iframe, might prove challenging because of the browser security model...

Answer (score 0):

Try using Event.MOUSE_LEAVE:

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.MOUSE_LEAVE,mouseLeaveHandler);

function mouseLeaveHandler(e:Event):void {
   trace("mouse left");
}
```